# Creating an Executable to Run a Hydrological Model Command via Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: windows, executable

I am a Hydrologist and am running a hydrological model on Windows using Ubuntu. I can run it by opening Ubuntu, navigating to the directory where I installed and compiled it, and then typing the command "mhm".

However, I need to create an .exe file that simply executes the "mhm" command within Ubuntu, so that I can point to it from an optimization software.

I'm not experienced in this, but I would appreciate a solution that I could research.

Thank you.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "an .exe file" - you could for example create an executable *wrapper script* or shell function that `cd`s to the directory and executes the program. OTOH if you are asking about creating a Windows binary executable version of the model that is a whole different thing.